# Why does the growth rate of integers $n$ for which $\varphi(x) = n$ has no solutions increase suddenly after a point?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, computational-mathematics

A [nontotient number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nontotient#targetText=Nontotient&targetText=There%20are%20infinitely%20many%20even,multiple%20which%20is%20a%20nontotient.) is an even natural number $n$ for which $\varphi(x) = n$ has no solutions, where $\varphi(x)$ is the Euler totient function. The smallest nontotient numbers are $$14, 26, 34, 38, 50, 62, 68, 74, 76, 86, 90, 94, 98, 114, 118, 122, 124, 134, \ldots$$

[image]

I generated the $n$-th nontotient number $T_n$ for all $n$ upto $10^2, 10^3, 10^4, 10^5, 10^6$ and and observed that the relation between $n$ and $T_n$ was almost perfectly linear. To test this intuition further, I generted the data for $n$ upto $10^7$ but this time, I observed that somewhere at about $n \approx 5.6 \times 10^6$ the linear relation breaks down and $T_n$ starts grown at a super linear rate i.e. faster than $n$.

**Question 1**: What is known about the growth rate of $T_n$?

**Question 2**: What is happening at about $n = 5.6 \times 10^6$ when $T_n$ when starts to quickly deviate away from linearity?

Comment: Nomenclature note: your list seems to be the list of all even nontotients (all odd numbers greater than 1 are also nontotients).

Comment: @GregMartin Since $2 | \varphi(n)$ for $n \ge 3$ hence trivially all odd numbers $> 1$ are non-totient so we are interested in the even non-totients. I have not stated this explicitly in the question

Comment: See Kevin Ford's paper 'The distribution of totients'.

Comment: @SungjinKim Thanks for telling me about this paper. I was computing on almost all the topics covered in this paper without know that they have already been studied. This saved me a lot of time.